# ¿Comó solucionar el problema de CORS Missing Allow Origin en angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Soy nuevo, hola.

Estoy desarrollando una app de prueba con spring boot y angular, y me he encontrado con el problema de `CORS Missing Allow Origin` al lado del cliente. Ya proporcione el `@CrossOrigin` en mi controlador y lo probe con Postman, y todo bien. Pero cuando lo pruebo desde al lado del cliente con angular, tengo problemas únicamente con el método `PUT`.

Este es mi código...

**Metódo PUT de mi *ProductoController***:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/producto")

public class ProductoController {

@Autowired
ProductoService productoService;

@GetMapping("/lista")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Producto>> list(){
        List<Producto> list = productoService.list();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Producto>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

@GetMapping("/detail/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Producto> getById(@PathVariable("id")int id){
        if(!productoService.existsById(id)) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("no existe"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }else {
            Producto producto = productoService.getOne(id).get();
            return new ResponseEntity<Producto>(producto, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

@PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody ProductoDto productoDto){
        if(!productoService.existsById(id))
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("no existe"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        if(productoService.existsByNombre(productoDto.getNombre()) && productoService.getByNombre(productoDto.getNombre()).get().getId() != id)
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("El nombre ya existe"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(productoDto.getNombre()))
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("El nombre es obligatorio"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        if(productoDto.getPrecio()<0)
            return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("El precio debe ser mayor a 0"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        Producto producto = productoService.getOne(id).get();
        producto.setNombre(productoDto.getNombre());
        producto.setPrecio(productoDto.getPrecio());
        productoService.save(producto);
        return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("producto actualizado"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**Mi servicio *producto.service.ts***:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Producto } from '../models/producto';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductoService {

  productoURL = 'http://localhost:8080/producto/';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public lista(): Observable<Producto[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Producto[]>(this.productoURL + 'lista');
  }

  public detalle(id: number): Observable<Producto>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Producto>(this.productoURL + `detail/${id}`);
  }

  public actualiza(id: number, producto: Producto): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.productoURL + `update/${id}`, producto);
  }

}
```

**El error**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar en angular. // cambiar post por put

```
public actualiza(id: number, producto: Producto): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.put<any>(this.productoURL + `update/${id}`, producto);
  }
```

y a una mala
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*") // todos los origines

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos.

Comment: Qué despistado!! Muchas gracias compañero, era poner el ```put``` en lugar del ```post```, gracias por el tiempo.